Run nslookup commands with Ruby to check DNS records
If I want the list of nameservers of a given domain name, I can use nslookup like that:
$ nslookup -type=NS stackoverflow.com
Server:     2a02:842a:8036:4801:5afc:20ff:fe6d:e07f
Address:    2a02:842a:8036:4801:5afc:20ff:fe6d:e07f#53

Non-authoritative answer:
stackoverflow.com   nameserver = sureena.ns.cloudflare.com.
stackoverflow.com   nameserver = damian.ns.cloudflare.com.

I'd like to do the same with Ruby. How can I do it?

You can use Resolv::DNS:
Resolv::DNS.open do |dns|
  dns.getresources "stackoverflow.com", Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::NS
end

[#<Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::NS:0x00007ffba1fe0f20
  @name=#<Resolv::DNS::Name: sureena.ns.cloudflare.com.>,
  @ttl=86400>,
 #<Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::NS:0x00007ffba1fe0458
  @name=#<Resolv::DNS::Name: damian.ns.cloudflare.com.>,
  @ttl=86400>]

You can use the following constants:

Nameserver: Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::NS
CNAME: Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::CNAME
MX: Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::MX
A: Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::A
TXT: Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::TXT

